# REGEXP to capture values delimited by a set of delimiters

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

My column value looks something like below: [Just an example i created]

`{BASICINFOxxxFyyy100x} {CONTACTxxx12345yyy20202x}`

It can contain 0 or more blocks of data... I have created the below query to split the blocks

```
with x as
 (select 
 '{BASICINFOxxxFyyy100x}{CONTACTxxx12345yyy20202x}' a from dual)
 select REGEXP_SUBSTR(a,'({.*?x})',1,rownum,null,1)
 from x
 connect by rownum <= REGEXP_COUNT(a,'x}')
```

However I would like to further split the output into 3 columns like below:

```
ColumnA    | ColumnB | ColumnC
------------------------------
BASICINFO  | F       |100
CONTACT    | 12345   |20202
```

The delimiters are always standard. I failed to create a pretty query which gives me the desired output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: List of ways to [split delimited string](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914140540/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/oracle/1968/splitting-delimited-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3a6f8/8)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( str ) AS
SELECT '{BASICINFOxxxFyyy100x}{CONTACTxxx12345yyy20202x}' from dual
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         t.str,
         '\{([^}]*?)xxx([^}]*?)yyy([^}]*?)x\}',
         1,
         l.COLUMN_VALUE,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS col1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         str,
         '\{([^}]*?)xxx([^}]*?)yyy([^}]*?)x\}',
         1,
         l.COLUMN_VALUE,
         NULL,
         2
       ) AS col2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         str,
         '\{([^}]*?)xxx([^}]*?)yyy([^}]*?)x\}',
         1,
         l.COLUMN_VALUE,
         NULL,
         3
       ) AS col3
FROM   your_table t
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.str,'\{([^}]*?)xxx([^}]*?)yyy([^}]*?)x\}')
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) l
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f3a6f8/8/0)**:

```
|      COL1 |  COL2 |  COL3 |
|-----------|-------|-------|
| BASICINFO |     F |   100 |
|   CONTACT | 12345 | 20202 |
```

*Note:*

Your query:

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(a,'({.*?x})',1,rownum,null,1)
from x
connect by rownum <= REGEXP_COUNT(a,'x}')
```

Will not work when you have multiple rows of input - In the `CONNECT BY` clause, the hierarchical query has nothing to restrict it connecting Row1-Level2 to Row1-Level1 or to Row2-Level1 so it will connect it to both and as the depth of the hierarchies gets greater it will create exponentially more duplicate copies of the output rows. There are hacks you can use to stop this but it is much more efficient to put the row generator into a correlated sub-query which can then be `CROSS JOIN`ed back to the original table (it is correlated so it won't join to the wrong rows) if you are going to use hierarchical queries.

Better yet would be to fix your data structure so you are not storing multiple values in delimited strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> with x as
  2   (select  '{BASICINFOxxxFyyy100x}{CONTACTxxx12345yyy20202x}' a from dual
  3   ),
  4  y as (
  5   select REGEXP_SUBSTR(a,'({.*?x})',1,rownum,null,1) c1
  6   from x
  7   connect by rownum <= REGEXP_COUNT(a,'x}')
  8  )
  9  select
 10    substr(c1,2,instr(c1,'xxx')-2) z1,
 11    substr(c1,instr(c1,'xxx')+3,instr(c1,'yyy')-instr(c1,'xxx')-3) z2,
 12    rtrim(substr(c1,instr(c1,'yyy')+3),'x}') z3
 13  from y;

Z1              Z2              Z3
--------------- --------------- ---------------
BASICINFO       F               100
CONTACT         12345           20202
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution, which is derived from the place you left. Your query had  already resulted into splitting of a row to 2 row. Below will make it in 3 columns:

```
WITH x
     AS (SELECT '{BASICINFOxxxFyyy100x}{CONTACTxxx12345yyy20202x}' a
           FROM DUAL),
-- Your query result here
     tbl
     AS (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (a,
                                   '({.*?x})',
                                   1,
                                   ROWNUM,
                                   NULL,
                                   1)
                       Col
               FROM x
         CONNECT BY ROWNUM <= REGEXP_COUNT (a, 'x}'))
--- Actual Query
SELECT col,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (col,
                      '(.*?{)([^x]+)',
                      1,
                      1,
                      '',
                      2)
          AS COL1,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (col,
                                     '(.*?)([^x]+)',
                                     1,
                                     2,
                                     '',
                                     2),
                      '[^y]+',
                      1,
                      1)
          AS COL2,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR (REGEXP_SUBSTR (col,
                                     '[^y]+x',
                                     1,
                                     2),
                      '[^x]+',
                      1,
                      1)
          AS COL3
  FROM tbl;
```

Output:

```
SQL> /

COL                                              COL1                                             COL2                                             COL3
------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------
{BASICINFOxxxFyyy100x}                           BASICINFO                                        F                                                100
{CONTACTxxx12345yyy20202x}                       CONTACT                                          12345                                            20202
```